# Problem with Install Tizen Studio 3.7/4.1 for Mac after update Big Sur

Tags: tizen, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, tizen-studio

I’ve upgraded to a new mac M1 and Big Sur and tried to install Tizen Studio 4.1. or 3.7. After many attempts to install it with IDE installer I finally achieved a step with the Software Agreement page. But, this Agreement window hangs out as if the focus on the buttons and window is lost and there is no way to bring it back. Possible GUI bug?

Has anyone encountered this problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with your problem. 
But, this looks like the same issue - https://www.reddit.com/r/Tizen/comments/n0g4zv/cant_tizen_studio_41_for_mac_with_latest_big_sur/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it was a bug. Now it solved, you can download new installer version from official site(4.1.1)

Comment: The issue was resolved in a new update. thanks for the info

https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/tizen-studio/download?langredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Already registered a Q&A for Samsung Support Team. Initial judgment is Tizen Studio installer not compatible with Big Sur 11.3 (latest update).

They will check and release an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue with
**Big Sur 11.5.2**
And **web-ide_Tizen_Studio_4.1.1_singapore_macos-64**

I have tried bellow command and then run the Installer

```
sudo spctl --master disable
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the specific `jdk` version required.
Take a look at the following instructions which we use: [Install Tizen Studio on Apple M1](https://remoteorigin.com/blog/install-tizen-studio-on-apple-m1/)